# Why can't I deposit to Goerli Aave with web3.py?

Tags: web3.py, aave

I'm trying to deposit weth to aave on the goerli testnet. My approveErc20 function works and I confirmed that tokens are approved for transfer. This is my code:

```
def deposit_to_aave_goerli(privateKey, amount, lending_pool, web3, nonce=None):
    account=web3.eth.account.from_key(privateKey).address
    lendCon = web3.eth.contract(address=lending_pool,abi=lending_pool_abi)
    nonce = nonce if nonce else web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account)
    weth_address = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6")
    tx = lendCon.functions.deposit(weth_address, amount, account, 0).buildTransaction(
        {
            "chainId": 5,
            "from": account,
            "nonce": nonce,
        }
    )
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=privateKey)
    tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    return web3.toHex(tx_hash)
```

I get a boatload of errors after this:

```
File "C:\Users\ilank\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\borrowLend.py", line 71, in deposit_to_aave_goerli
    tx = lendCon.functions.deposit(weth_address, amount, account, 0).buildTransaction(
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\decorators.py", line 51, in wrapper
    return to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1112, in buildTransaction
    return self.build_transaction(transaction)
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1099, in build_transaction
    return build_transaction_for_function(
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1672, in build_transaction_for_function
    prepared_transaction = fill_transaction_defaults(web3, prepared_transaction)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 249, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\transactions.py", line 114, in fill_transaction_defaults     
    default_val = default_getter(web3, transaction)
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\transactions.py", line 60, in <lambda>
    'gas': lambda web3, tx: web3.eth.estimate_gas(tx),
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 868, in estimate_gas
    return self._estimate_gas(transaction, block_identifier)
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 170, in formatted_response
    apply_error_formatters(error_formatters, response)
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 70, in apply_error_formatters
    formatted_resp = pipe(response, error_formatters)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 666, in cytoolz.functoolz.pipe
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 641, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe
  File "C:\Users\ilank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\method_formatters.py", line 576, in raise_solidity_error_on_revert
    raise ContractLogicError(response['error']['message'])
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: 2
```

I took the ABI from etherscan, got the lendingPool from aave's lending_pool_address_provider (and confirmed that it was correct),and followed all of Aave's docs. What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, solved. There are like a thousand weth contracts on goerli, you have to use the specific one for Aave's test network. Same with all the other erc20s, you have to get a faucet from the Aave testnet app.